# How to add a class to change custom pointer/cursor size on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

does anybody know how to add a class which triggers the scale of the custom cursor when the class .clickable is detected on mouseover. I added my approach to this project down below. Thanks for your suggestions.

```js
var $cursor = $('.cursor');

function moveCursor(e) {
  $cursor.css({
    "top": e.pageY,
    "left": e.pageX
  });
}

$(window).on('mousemove', moveCursor);

$(".clickable").mouseover(function() {
  $("cursor").addClass(".is-clickable");
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clickable {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.cursor.is-clickable {
  transform: scale(0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="background-color:black;">
  <div class="cursor"></div>
  <div class="clickable"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Typo `$("cursor")`

Comment: Another typo `addClass(".is-clickable");`  should be `addClass("is-clickable");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had 2 typos and in case the idea was to change cursor size when only inside of "clickable" element you'd need add `mouseout` event to remove the class:

```js
var $cursor = $('.cursor');

function moveCursor(e) {
  $cursor.css({
    "top": e.pageY,
    "left": e.pageX
  });
}

$(window).on('mousemove', moveCursor);

$(".clickable").mouseover(function() {
  $cursor.addClass("is-clickable");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $cursor.removeClass("is-clickable");
});
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
}

.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clickable {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.cursor.is-clickable {
  transform: scale(0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="background-color:black;">
  <div class="cursor"></div>
  <div class="clickable"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `.toggleClass("is-clickable", true);` is the same as `.addClass("is-clickable")`, it won't add it multiple times and especially if you're also removing it before re-adding.

Comment: Oh? thanks, didn't know that.